# Composition of polynomials and Zariski-topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, roots, function-and-relation-composition, zariski-topology

I am learning algebraic geometry and have a rather vague question about the the correspondence between polynomial ideals and closed sets in the Zariski-topology in the context of composition of polynomials.

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be an algebraically closed field, polynomials $f,g_1,...,g_n\in\mathbb{K}[x_1,...,x_n]$ and $\overline{\tau}_{\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{K}^n}$ be the set of (Zariski-)closed sets (e.g. $Z(f)\in\overline{\tau}_{\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{K}^n}$ is the zero locus or algebraic set of the ideal $(f)$...). As we have basic identities like $Z(g_1\cdot g_2)=Z(g_1)\cup Z(g_2)$ and $Z(g_1,g_2)=Z(g_1)\cap Z(g_2)$ I wonder if there are also identities of the kind
\begin{align}
Z(f(g_1,...,g_n))=\theta(Z(f),Z(g_1),...,Z(g_n))
\end{align}
for some $n+1$-ary function $\theta:\left(\overline{\tau}_{\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{K}^n}\right)^{n+1}\to\overline{\tau}_{\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{K}^n}$. I did never encounter this situation in my algebraic geometry literature. Is there any material on this?

Answer (score 1):

$g_1, \cdots, g_n$ together define a morphism $g: \Bbb K^n \to \Bbb K^n$.

$$\begin{array}{cl}
& Z(f(g_1, \cdots, g_n)) \\
=& \{ x \in \Bbb K^n \mid f(g_1(x), \cdots, g_n(x)) = 0 \} \\
=& \{ x \in \Bbb K^n \mid (g_1(x), \cdots, g_n(x)) \in Z(f) \} \\
=& \{ x \in \Bbb K^n \mid g(x) \in Z(f) \} \\
=& g^{-1}(Z(f))
\end{array}$$

I am afraid there might be no expression strictly of the form you want; this is the best I can do.

Comment: It is a useful identity, but not what I was looking for since the morphism $g$ is determined by the polynomials $g_1,...,g_n$ and not by the ideals $(g_1),...,(g_n)$ or algebraic sets $Z(g_1),...,Z(g_n)$. But yes, probably such expression does not exist in the form of how my question was stated. Probably the question should be restated in the form of composition of polynomial ideals.